# how to apply styles for selected item in the kendo menu

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I am using Kendo Menu,
I am trying to apply styles for selected item in the menu.
I have tried like

```
.k-menu .k-state-selected> .k-link {
    color: lightcoral;
}
```

It is not worked out in my case.
can any one help me to fix this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not such concept of selected option. You have a `select` event but it does not stay `selected`. So, you should do it by yourself.

```
$("#menu").kendoMenu({
    select: function (e) {
        // Remove previously selected options for this menu
        $(".k-state-selected", this.element).removeClass("k-state-selected");
        // Select item
        $(e.item).addClass("k-state-selected")
    }
});
```

With this, you can use the style as you defined:

```
.k-menu .k-state-selected> .k-link {
    color: lightcoral;
}
```

Example in here http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/7bk2h/1/

Comment: not in mouse over,when I select(click) a particular item in menu,I have to apply styles for that.I want to display variation for selected and remaining.

Comment: I don't have children,I have only top level menu

Comment: AFAIK there is not such concept of menu item selected. You have a `select` event but the option does not stay _selected_ you should implement it by yourself (see edition)